# "Private" data in ID3 tags created by Music

Tags: macos, music, metadata, id3-tag, exif

Music.app deleted 21 or more audio files [in an unexpected way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/442226/how-does-music-know-that-an-mp3-file-was-copied-from-it).  **Some** of those files have "Private" ID3 data which exiftool says has an “Invalid ID3 frame size.”  Some of the files with the Private data were **not** undesirably deleted.  So, I believe the presence of this data is unrelated to the other issue.

But I wonder what the data is and why it was added to ten of 49 files which were all created the same way.

eyeD3 says `PRIV: [Data: 395 bytes]` for six; four have 361 bytes.

exiftool says `Private: (Binary data 380 bytes, use -b option to extract)` with the four saying 346 bytes.  So, *all* differ by 34 bytes, which maybe explains why exiftool also says `Warning: Invalid ID3 frame size`.

Dumping this private data to one file and running `strings` on it gave (among other things) “Abplist00” so I renamed it to temp.plist and tried to open it with XCode.  XCode complained “Failed to open property list: Conversion of string failed.”

Anyone able to tell me what these might be and why they are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My misconception: it was not created by Music.app, but by Amadeus Pro when I edited those files.

Update: It is a bug that the author of Amadeus is aware of.  He didn’t say whether the bug is in Amadeus or in MacOS, but he has a version that either fixes or avoids the bug.

To reproduce, set all your MacOS encoding settings to UTF-8.  Open an MP3 file in Amadeus (the official version on the date I posted).  Add at least one marker, and put the name of the marker in Greek.  Save the file and use exiftool and/or eyeD3 to examine the tags.

I offer the possibility that the bug is in the Music app because I have seen errors in the Get Info window for files that Amadeus had not edited.

Comment: Good sleuthing - is there a way to reproduce or document this so that it will help others?